# Experimentally diminishing random errors for low wavelength UV observations

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, error-analysis

Part of the work that I do involves observations of solar low wavelength UV observations, specifically UV-B and UV-A II (up to 340nm).  I have noticed that when I observe responses on a CCD or CMOS based sensor, that the lower the wavelength observed the greater the random fluctuations in the pixel responses.  This is also noted in the paper [Evaluating UVA Aerosol Optical Depth using a Smartphone Camera](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/php.12082/abstract) (abstract only), that suggests reason as being

> The greater relative error occurs at lower wavelengths (340 nm) due to increased atmospheric scattering effects, particularly at higher air masses and due to lower signal to noise ratio in the image sensor.

So, the question is **how is it possible to experimentally diminish the random noise from low wavelength UV observations, while preserving as much of the signal as possible?**

Comment: Woot! This is a really well posed and interesting experimental question. Arise, ye experimentalists of the 'net! Bring forth relevant information.

Comment: When you say there is greater fluctuations, do you mean that the CCD counts fluctuate more at lower wavelengths, or something else? Do you use a laser to calibrate atmospheric density fluctuations?

Comment: @DanielSank, yes, the CCD/CMOS pixel counts/responses fluctuate.  We use sunphotometers (e.g. Microtops II) for calibration

Comment: Are the fluctuations spatially correlated? With higher energy photons (I think 340 nm is beyond the direct gap of silicon), you may be getting charge bleeding between pixels.

Comment: Follow up: It looks like the direct gap of silicon is 3.4 eV.  So $\lambda = hc/E = 1240 \text{ eV}\,\text{nm} / 3.4 \text{eV} = 365 \text{nm}$.  Maybe this is unrelated though.  What material is your CMOS CCD?

Comment: @CuriousKev the CCD/CMOS used is the standard silicon, silicon dioxide semiconductor - you have given me something to ponder!

Comment: @CuriousKev: Why would charge bleeding get worse at lower wavelength?

Comment: @DanielSank Just something to consider, it could be nothing.  Beyond the direct band gap the silicon is strongly optically active everywhere (not just at some specially prepared photo active region) so my thought was free charges may pop up where they are not intended, possibly allowing conduction where it is not intended.

Comment: When you say the SNR gets worse at lower wavelengths, is it because the signal is going down or because the noise is going up?

Comment: The noise appears to be increasing

Comment: Are you focusing the UV with lenses on your detectors? ( I am thinking on the lines of seeing stars in the noise  with telescopes)

Comment: @annav Yes, the lenses themselves focus the UV image to a square approximately 30 x 30 pixels.

Comment: Well, then use a stronger "telescope". If the noise is coming from the atmosphere this should strengthen the signal to noise.

Comment: It's not just photon shot noise right?

Comment: How are you performing dark current and gain calibration?

Comment: @CuriousOne not too bad - I can certainly get access to the equipment to do this - do you have something in mind?

Comment: @Omen: I was just wondering how well your camera performs in general and how you are calibrating the raw data. For dark calibration one would need some kind of a shutter, I guess, and gain calibration... that's a whole different can of worms. It would probably require a photometer, but at least a precision photo diode in addition to the camera? Is there something like that in the setup?

Comment: @CuriousOne yes, we used a photometer in the calibration.

Comment: @Omen: Do you mean "used once" or "use every day"? What's the result for the stability of both calibration points?

Comment: Wonder if this is still of interest. Two thoughts. (1) Use a filter which is relatively transparent to UV, but opaque to visible light. (2) Cool the detector and the preamp.